# Join County Data by state and county name without FIPS - join by two attributes?

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

I have data by county that I want to join with census data but when I do the join by county name it messes up because some states have the same county names and I don't know how to get around this without manually adding FIPS to all the counties. Is there a way to do a join by saying to make sure the State and County match, not just the County name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a new field using the Field Calculator that combines county and state. Do this for both of the tables you are trying to join. Then join based on your new County+State field.